# Babel.js was not loaded on Systemjs's transpiler

Tags: javascript, reactjs, babeljs, systemjs

In using [babel](/questions/tagged/babel) as transpiler of [systemjs](/questions/tagged/systemjs), I encountered this error at chrome console.

```
Potentially unhandled rejection [2] Error loading "test" at test.js
Error evaluating test.js
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token < (WARNING: non-Error used)
```

I have doubt that `JSX` transpiling was failed because [babel](/questions/tagged/babel) was not loaded. Exactly There is not calling `browser.min.js`(babel-browser) stack in chrome's network-tab.

You can see code on [here](https://gist.github.com/jeyraof/56993a8c4ebc041097aa).

Comment: Give [jspm](http://jspm.io/) a try, it sets all of that up for you.

Comment: @elclanrs same error was happend..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found solution.

I changed it:

```
var React = require('React');
```

to

```
import React from 'react';
```

ES6 code of target js file call babel.